# Getting issues when producing a dll file after binding an Objective-C static library to Xamarin.iOS

Tags: dll, xamarin.ios

Steps :

1. I already have an iOS app that I need to convert into a .dll file so that I may build it in Xamarian.iOS.
2. Create an .a FAT file by converting my app to an Objective-C static library.
3. I created Xamarian.iOS application after producing .a file. All of our classes and functions are used in the binding-based iOS application.
4. Using objective sharpie, I created the files ApiDefination.cs and Struct.cs.

Actual Result:
After implementing binding and adding new ApiDefination and Stuct files, the project gives me dozens of problems when I run it. Even after resolving all of these problems, my trampoline.g.cs file is still giving me errors.

This photo serves as a reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmZzO.png)

Expected Result:
Successfully produce .dll file that I can use with Xamarin.iOS without experiencing a single problem .

Reference Document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=macos

Video for Reference: https://youtu.be/sNq3CjrdK8g

Software version:
Visual Studio for Mac: 8.10.25(build 2)
Xcode: Version 14.0.1
Visual Studio code : 1.72.2

Environment:
MacOS Monterey Version 12.6

Comment: First, you can clean the bin and obj file and rebuild them. Second, you can check your code in the trampoline.g.cs. the errors are the format error.

Comment: Thanks for the response but have already tried that but didn't work.